# No console output available on linux when executing grails/groovy

Tags: linux, grails, command-line

When a groovy script or a grails app is executed, there is no output/input available -> just a clear console screen. Even without starting the X-Window-System, the output is not visible.

I tried also:

- grails compile --plain-output (does not work too)
- executing grails commands in IntelliJ (works fine with grailsCommand, but not on CommandLine)

How can the output made visible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of grails?

```
env|grep JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/

env|grep GRAILS
GRAILS_HOME=/home/vahid/ggts-bundle/grails-2.3.7/

which grails
grails is aliased to `/home/vahid/ggts-bundle/grails-2.3.7/bin/grails'

alias|grep grails
alias grails='/home/vahid/ggts-bundle/grails-2.3.7/bin/grails'
```

Do you see anything actually being done, or is it after completion that it does not show up?

```
grails refresh-dependencies --plain-output 2>&1 > /tmp/vh.txt
```

The above redirected all output to /tmp/vh.txt

```
cat /tmp/vh.txt 
|Loading Grails 2.3.7
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
....
|Dependencies refreshed.
```

Comment: Perfect, JAVA_HOME was not set and this error was not displayed.