# Running Grails in Command prompt

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using mac os mavericks. When i type grails -version in the terminal, a message shows like this

```
Jun 12, 2014 4:04:27 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class[org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Jun 12, 2014 4:04:27 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
```

I can't execute commands like create-app also, the error message says,

```
Error Script not found for name grails create-app r
```

What could be the problem in this one?

Comment: Hi Katherine have you exported JAVA_HOME? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898860/no-console-output-available-on-linux-when-executing-grails-groovy/23913667#23913667

Comment: The warnings are from Groovy as you're using Java < 7.  They can be ignored (I believe they are not printed in later groovy versions)

Comment: @vahid not yet. Could this be the problem?

Comment: possibly - although I know mac and JAVA works slightly different to Linux.. no harm in ensuring your JAVA_HOME GRAILS_HOME etc are all set and attempting it again.

Comment: it was JAVA_HOME for me (Mac OS X Yosemite)