# grails application terminating automatically

Tags: grails

I am doing sample application from git-hub [book-flow] I created domain classes,controller classes and also views  of the book -flow application, then `I executed the application  in development mode but the application is terminated automatically` in console it showed

```
Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Running Grails application
```

I unable to find where is the problem and **I want to know that where can I find the applications on grails other than github**.

Comment: If you are unable to run the app, then check `stacktrace.log` in target directory of the app.

Comment: https://grails.org/learn

Comment: can you update your question and provide what github project you are talking of ? https://github.com/grails-samples/book-flow I found this but the project is from 7 years ago according to https://github.com/grails-samples/book-flow/blob/master/application.properties it is grails 0.6. Not that any of that nor git source being the issue - since if you have recreated the classes etc rather than cloning the project - then its a fresh project under 2.1.1 so grails run-app --stacktrace would probably be a place to start

Comment: @vahid I recreated the application, while I am executing the application server is terminating automatically, can you provide the grails 2.1.1 sample project details where I get real time applications knowledge

Comment: @dmahapatro the application  does not have the stacktrace.log file in its target directory

Comment: @srujan unsure what you mean - I think you need to understand the basics of grails its not version specific - in grails 2.1.1 create a domain class called test put String name inside it then generate controllers/views and run app  that is the most basic example of a grails project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Srujan

I thought I give you more of an insight into grails now that I have a little time on my hands...

most of the grails should remember one day not too long ago we were also in the same boat and had no idea where to start...

I would suggest getting hold of a good book such as definitive guide to grails 2 and reading/experimenting....

To create a basic app with one object :

The following is using grails command line - so refer to [No console output available on linux when executing grails/groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898860/no-console-output-available-on-linux-when-executing-grails-groovy/23913667#23913667) for expoerting out java grails - I Guess you are windows so same but on windows environment...

```
$ grails create-app grails-example
$ cd grails-example
$ grails create-domain-class Books
$ vi grails-app/domain/grails/example/Books.groovy
```

> cat grails-app/domain/grails/example/Books.groovy

```
package grails.example

class Books {

    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

vi is a linux editing tool so use notepad and go to that path and as you can see I added

String name

save file now run:

```
$ grails generate-controller grails.example.Books
$ grails generate-view Books
$ grails generate-view grails.example.Books
$ grails run-app
```

As for general beginners guide, I came across this site today and have probably used in the past without noticing it...

http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners/

Best of luck and welcome to Grails. I have enjoyed every moment of working with it...